# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: android, jvm, android-studio

I recently started to change Eclipse to a new Android Studio IDE and the IDE found problems.

I created suscesfully a new project but at the moment of the first build, appears 
the next errors.
i dont even typed any code.

> Compilation completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings in 17 sec 3 errors
>   0 warnings Gradle: : Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Gradle: : A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. Gradle:
>   Execution failed for task ':Motelalpaso:dexDebug'.
>
> > Running C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\17.0.0\dx.bat failed. See output

Im working on Windows 7 
and i have this java version on the folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17.

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I hope your help
Thanks